# How to load more resources which are out of the application env?

Tags: php, zend-framework, initialization, zend-config

I have a application.ini like this

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[database]
resources.db.adapter               = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.dbname         = "ccgss"
resources.db.params.username       = "root"
resources.db.params.password       = ""
resources.db.params.hostname       = "localhost"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

[layout]
layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
layout = default
contentKey = "content"
```

By default, zend framework loads the `[production]` section. How do I load automatically the others sections?

**Additionally**

How do I change the environments between `staging`, `testing`, `development` and on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch your application's environments between production, development, etc. simply set the variable to appropriate value in your `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

If you'd like to auto-load your own [resource plugins](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/231-Creating-Re-Usable-Zend_Application-Resource-Plugins.html) from the bootstrap, you can do that by just tacking it onto the `resources` array:

```
resources.myplugin.param1 = "myvalue"
```

Don't forget to add your plugin's namespace and directory path to the `pluginsPath` value as well, or ZF won't know where to look:

```
pluginPaths.My_Resource_Namespace = "My/Namespace/Folder"
```

Finally, if you want to acces values in your config file without using a `resources` plugin, you can load the file using the [Zend_Config_Ini](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html) class:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/config.ini', 'staging');
```

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework loads 'production' section because your environment is set to 'production' in your index.php

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

So to change your environment to something other than production, you simply need to change value of `APPLICATION_ENV` variable (you can do this in .htaccess for instance).

Besides, you probably don't need separate sections for database and layout, just include them into 'production' section. If you use separate sections for them, they are not parsed because only the current environment section is parsed, as you can see from this line

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
  APPLICATION_ENV,
  APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
```